# Wordpress - polylang in command launch post traduction

Tags: wordpress, xliff, polylang, wp-cli

Today I need some help with Wordpress, as is is far from being my cup of tea.

Currently, I'm tring to create a plugin to export translation from post in a xliff file then reimport this xliff file to set the translation. This plugin we only be used If wordpress uses polylang for translations. For now I'm only exporting meta data.

I've managed to find how polylang is linking two post, saying this one is in english and this one is in french. So for now I have a command to export a post in a xliff file, and a command to import a traduction from an xliff file.

Everything work fine as long, as the post I'm trying to translate already has existing translation (basically I'm just updating meta data).

But my problem, is when I have a post in french, but I do not have a matching post in english.

What I wanted to do was to do, was to create the missing post and after overwrite the meta data.

But I do not know how to create the missing post as a copy of my post and saying that this one is in english. Does anyone know how I can do that from my command ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found what I wanted. Polylang has commande line for duplicating a post in an other language. And I just had to use \WP_CLI::runcommand

```
$options = array(
                    'return'     => true,
                    'parse'      => 'json',
                    'launch'     => false,
                    'exit_error' => true,
                );
$command = 'pll post duplicate ' . $idPost . ' ' . $destLocale;
\WP_CLI::runcommand($command, $options);
```